# Create Bulk Certificates By Account Owner

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-slides

is this possible in Google Slides with GAS? If so, I hope someone can help me.

I have two templates of certificate. 1 template is for Accounts with 100% score, and another template for Accounts with scores below 99%.

Here is the Google Sheet data source.

[**Test File Certificates**] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1negtTNpsyLJDghquVa3SJLkYFFv4vVpDRB_G0u7pYl4)

What I want to happen are the ff:

1. If account's score is 100%, use template1. If below 100%, use template2.
2. If account belongs to same Owner, the certificates should only be in one Google Slide file.

For example, since Jason has 2 accounts, his slide with his name on file name will contain 2 pages, 1 page for template1 and another page for template2. Same for Cero, but both pages are template2. Then Alie's google slide file will only have 1 certificate with the template1 format.

3. Copied certificates must be save into a specific drive.

Templates has the same format. Just has Account and Month in it. The difference between the two is just the picture.

[Template for 100%](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1m0_rWaiCe2KdlkKWbzomlgQGJHffA584BURjciBdEYM/edit?usp=drivesdk)

[Template for below or equal to 99%](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1xrxVSIlbLTNob-7PwngSz93Q_ufDNMad9gGdpLCIjXc/edit?usp=drivesdk)

Can these be done? I hope someone can help/guide me.

Comment: I believe it’s possible to create emailable certificates.

Comment: perhaps this sample script can help you: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/samples/automations/employee-certificate